# Pillow (PIL) showing "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have this captcha I need to extract the text from.

I've been using Pillow to get this done and I have tried numerous other libs straight from github and none of them are working. With the pillow, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Competitions/Donations/Scrapping.py", line 111, in <module>
    Scrapping()
  File "F:/Competitions/Donations/Scrapping.py", line 57, in __init__
    myText = image_to_string(Image.open(filePath), config='-psm 10')
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line     161, in image_to_string
config=config)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Pythons\Python3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Pythons\Python3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is an error based on `image_to_string` method and I can't get my head around to solve this issue. Any recommendations for this?

This is the code I'm using :

```
myText = image_to_string(Image.open(filePath))
```

`filePath` is the path to the image.

P.S : The captcha image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgWM0.jpg

Comment: It would simply appear that `filePath` is incorrect, or otherwise non-existent.

Comment: The error message says your code is `myText = image_to_string(Image.open(filePath), config='-psm 10')`

Comment: tried 2 ways. The one I posted and another command to check where it is wrong. This error is fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have `tesseract` installed or on your `PATH`

From [the directions](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#installation) you need to be able to invoke `tesseract` from the commandline.

The actual error you're getting has nothing to do with `PIL` or `Pillow` (notice how none of the `PIL` files are listed in your stacktrace).

The actual error comes from [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/636a831f9ba51ae7b364b09575c49f4b0c9e967e/src/pytesseract.py#L46) subprocessing out to `tesseract`

Comment: Just double checked and I can launch `tesseract` from my command line. Here : http://imgur.com/3Invnix

Comment: Okay, this worked now. I just closed my IDE, rerun it and it works now. wth :/